Breathing while working
Some part of my mind always watches/is aware of breath whether I am studying, playing, eating, watching movies, etc.
Is it ok? Any long detailed answer?

I want some scientific answer..

It’s ok to watch breath while doing other things. But it will not concentrate your mind. When walking focus only on walking. When lying focus only on lying. When watching movie focus only on movie. When cooking focus only on cooking.  When breathing focus only on breathing. Every activity has intermediary steps. Focus on every step. Be situationally aware depending on priority.

As simple as this answer is, it's correct. Hence why satiphattana practice focuses even more sublte of just sensory perceptions, When seeing focus on seeing, smelling, hearing, thinking. It is just mindfulness of the mental object, not specifically breathing. Unless of course breathing is the intended object.

@SacrificialEquation its unintentional

It's said to be very good. Knowing something is happening while it's happening is a lot better than merely acceptable, and it's certainly not the kind of thing that could be considered not okay; unless you're doing something dangerous and cause an accident because you're not paying enough attention to that, then it would be a moral and/or practical mistake.
Mindfulness of the body or some aspect of it, including breathing, is standard practice, recommended by many authoritative sources, whether in sitting meditation, or (ideally) without interruption throughout the day. They say continuity is key. And I think having a certain "theme" or object as an anchor can make it less likely to get distracted and go off chasing some thought or perception, only to wake up later from the daydream wondering what happened.

Mindfulness of in-&-out breathing, when developed & pursued, is of great fruit, of great benefit. Mindfulness of in-&-out breathing, when developed & pursued, brings the four frames of reference to their culmination. The four frames of reference, when developed & pursued, bring the seven factors for awakening to their culmination. The seven factors for awakening, when developed & pursued, bring clear knowing & release to their culmination. -MN 118
 
Wisdom comes from being mindful in all postures. Your practice should begin as soon as you awaken in the morning and continue until you fall asleep. Don't be concerned about how long you can sit. What's important is only that you keep watchful, whether you're walking or sitting or going to the bathroom. -Ajahn Chah, "A Still Forest Pool"


Lord Buddha said to Venerable Ananda that he was aware of Breath and Death with every inbreath and out breath.
Such was the power of His mindfulness.
So for us, if we develop Dana, Sila, Bhavana as lay people or Sila, Samadhi, Punnya as meditator's then what ever we can do to develop our Sati and remove unwholesome thoughts, we try develop the first foundation of mindfulness as our basis, as this is Lord Buddha's directive.
So developing a formal meditation object is important, but so to it is important to develop mindfulness, and wholesome qualities from the moment we open our eyes, to the moment we fall asleep.
Lord Buddha said one who practice mindfulness of breathing will even know the very last in breath and out breath as they are dying. So these are supreme levels of mindfulness we are trying to cultivate.
